# parsing a logfile for error messages

Tags: bash, grep, find

I'm trying to write a bash command able to set a variable (exitStatus) based on the scanning of a log file for a specific pattern.

Inside the log file, many error messages can be present.  The problem is that one
error message is sometimes written on two lines.  For example:

```
ERROR 77: Invalid record detected at position 88332: bad alignment 
detected [IRD-21]
ERROR 77: Invalid record detected at position 88333: bad alignment 
detected [IRD-21]
ERROR 77: Invalid record detected at position 88334: bad alignment 
detected [IRD-21]
ERROR 77: Invalid record detected at position 88335: bad alignment 
detected [IRD-21]
ERROR 88: Bad format in string at record 287 [SYN-44]
ERROR 88: Bad format in string at record 288 [SYN-44]
ERROR 88: Bad format in string at record 289 [SYN-44]
ERROR 73: Invalid table spec or stub at record 1022 [INVT-33]
```

If the log file ONLY contains messages related to ERROR 77 [IRD-21], or if there are no errors at all then it's fine, exitStatus remains to 0.  Otherwise, exitStatus is set to 2.

I've been trying with find and grep but the fact that an error message can spread over two lines is destroying my efforts.  Simply put, I'd like to ask the shell: "hey, bash, does the log file contains other errors than IRD-21?, if so, raise an error".

Also, I have no control on the log file format, it comes from our client.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if there's the word `ERROR` followed by something other than `77`, then you can do (with GNU grep):

```
exitStatus=$(grep -qP 'ERROR (?!77)' sample.log && echo 2 || echo 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will basically delete the lines which starts with  `ERROR 77` and ends with `21]`

```
sed -i.bak '/ERROR 77*/ {N; /ERROR 77.*21\]/d }' log_file
```

Then you can use your grep command with your new log file to find if there are any other error message in your log file

```
exit_status=$(grep  -q "ERROR" log_file && echo 2 || echo 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to join back lines which do not start with ERROR so you can then filter out the ERROR 77:s.

```
awk '!/^ERROR/ && n { print; n=0; next }
    n { printf "\n" }
    { printf "%s", $0; n=1 }' log
```

This is quick and dirty and only works with a single folded line, but seems to sort out your sample log file snippet.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input.  I'd like to add that the OS is Solaris, therefore, the syntax is somewhat different for grep for example...  Also, I just discovered that some error messages do not have numbers so, instead of "ERROR 77", the logfile reads: "ERROR: invalid header, please review your specs".